# What am I missing for determining the winner by votes?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, global

I'm trying to think of a way to make functions that determine the winner of an election by most votes, as well as a function that determines a winner-takes-all rule.

My code is as follows:

```
_base_dict = {}
    
def add_state(name: str, votes: dict[str, int]) -> None:
    global _base_dict

    for name, votes in _base_dict.items():
        _base_dict[name] += votes

def winner(college: dict[str, int]) -> str:

    global _base_dict

    rv = None
    bigger_percentage = 0

    for state, total_votes in college.items():
        majority = total_votes // 2

        for name, votes in _base_dict.items():
            if votes[state] > majority:
                percentage = votes[state] / float(total_votes)
                if percentage > bigger_percentage:
                    bigger_percentage = percentage
                    rv = name
                elif percentage == bigger_percentage:
                    rv = None
    
    if rv is None: 
        return "No Winner"
    return rv

def clear() -> None:    

    global _base_dict

    _base_dict.clear()
    _base_dict.update(_base_dict)
```

and on a test file, I am running the functions through this:

```
import elections
college = {'Virginia': 13,
'Ohio': 18,
'Minnesota': 10,
'Alabama': 9,
'Maine': 4
}

print(elections.winner({}))

elections.add_state('Virginia', {
'Turing': 15,
'Lovelace': 20,
'Dijkstra': 10
})

elections.add_state('Ohio', {
'Turing': 1,
'Dijkstra': 15
})

elections.add_state('Alabama', {
'Turing': 10,
'Lovelace': 20,
'Dijkstra': 8
})

print(elections.winner(college))

elections.add_state('Minnesota', {
'Lovelace': 10,
'Dijkstra': 30,
})

elections.add_state('Florida', {
'Turing': 10,
'Lovelace': 30,
'Dijkstra': 15
})

print(elections.winner(college))

elections.clear()
elections.add_state('Maine', {
'Turing': 2,
'Dijkstra': 1,
'Lovelace': 5
})
print(elections.winner(college))
```

My desired output is:

```
No Winner
Lovelace
Dijkstra
Lovelace
```

but I keep getting:

```
No Winner
No Winner
No Winner
No Winner
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. Any help is appreciated.
Edit: I prefer to use logic to solve this issue, though imports are also appreciated.

Comment: Could you please describe the error/traceback you're receiving?

Comment: Funnily enough, there is no error, but it just keeps returning No Winner, No Winner, No Winner, No Winner. I will add that to the initial post now.

Comment: Look at the "logic" of your `add_state` method. It actually doesn't make any sense. For every name in `_base_dict` you are mathematically adding an entire dictionary.

Comment: Okay, I can see that it essentially does nothing. How would I then take in where it stores the correct values?

Comment: I take back my answer. Your `add_state` function should just be `_base_dict[statename] = votedict`. It seems your biggest issue is very poor naming. If this stuff was named properly, you wouldn't be doing a bunch of unnecessary stuff. It would be more obvious where you break your logic. Think about it, what is a `_base_dict`? It's a nothing, is what it is. How about `states` or `votes_by_state`? Name things what they are and life gets much easier.

Comment: I think I might have a fix for you - but are you sure your last winner should be Lovelace and not Dijkstra, as you have the votes tallied currently?

Comment: Yes, the last winner should be Lovelace.

Comment: All good - I just re ran my fix - realised I'd missed one "clear" call - get the expected result now - see the answer I've just posted.

Answer (score 0):

I think this fixes it:

First off, I suggest `_base_dict` needs to be a `defaultdict` - so you can add `keys` to it that it doesn't already have. Like so:

```
from collections import defaultdict

_base_dict = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(lambda: 0))
```

Defined thus, every time you invoke `_base_dict[<some state name>]`, if that state name is not already a key in `_base_dict`, the key gets added to `_base_dict`, and the value assigned to that key becomes another `defaultdict` whose keys will be candidate names, and whose vote count for that state will start off at `0`.

Secondly, I'm uncomfortable with the `global _base_dict` business - that probably says more about me than about your code, but to keep my sanity I've worked around it by defining `_base_dict` at the beginning, and then passing it to `add_state` and `winner` on each of their calls. `add_state` takes in `_base_dict`, modifies it, and then returns it. This will probably drive functional programming aficionados crazy - and I apologise - I'm sure given more time I could come up with something a little more elegant.

```
def add_state(statename: str, statevotes: dict, _base_dict: dict) -> dict:
    

    for candidatename, candidatevotes in statevotes.items():
        _base_dict[statename][candidatename] += candidatevotes
        
    return _base_dict
```

`winner` then takes in both `college` (a `dict` with state names for its `keys` and `int` for its `values`), and `_base_dict` - already defined above. I've rewritten `winner` below:

```
def winner(college: dict, _base_dict: dict) -> str:

    rv = None
    bigger_percentage = 0

    for state, total_votes in college.items():
        majority = total_votes // 2
        for candidatename, candidatevotes in _base_dict[state].items():
            if candidatevotes > majority:
                percentage = candidatevotes / float(total_votes)
                if percentage > bigger_percentage:
                    bigger_percentage = percentage
                    rv = candidatename
                elif percentage == bigger_percentage:
                    rv = None
    if rv is None:
        return "No Winner"
    return rv
```

I admit I haven't thought too deeply about the exact vote-counting logic here, I've simply adapted your original code to suit the changes I'm describing here.

Lastly, `clear` is redefined to accept `_base_dict`, and return it, like so:

```
def clear(_base_dict: dict) -> dict:    

    _base_dict.clear()
    _base_dict.update(_base_dict)
    return _base_dict
```

Putting it all together and running through the remainder of your script:

```
college = {'Virginia': 13,
'Ohio': 18,
'Minnesota': 10,
'Alabama': 9,
'Maine': 4
}

print(winner(college,_base_dict))

_base_dict = add_state('Virginia', {'Turing': 15,
                                    'Lovelace': 20,
                                    'Dijkstra': 10}, 
                       _base_dict)

_base_dict = add_state('Ohio', {'Turing': 1,
                                'Dijkstra': 15
                                }, 
                       _base_dict)

_base_dict = add_state('Alabama', {'Turing': 10,
                                   'Lovelace': 20,
                                   'Dijkstra': 8}, 
                       _base_dict)

print(winner(college, _base_dict))

_base_dict = add_state('Minnesota', {'Lovelace': 10,
                                     'Dijkstra': 30,}, 
                       _base_dict)

_base_dict = add_state('Florida', {'Turing': 10,
                                   'Lovelace': 30,
                                   'Dijkstra': 15}, 
                       _base_dict)

print(winner(college, _base_dict))

_base_dict = clear(_base_dict)

_base_dict = add_state('Maine', {'Turing': 2,
                                 'Dijkstra': 1,
                                 'Lovelace': 5}, 
                       _base_dict)

print(winner(college, _base_dict))
```

We get:

```
No Winner
Lovelace
Dijkstra
Lovelace
```

Just as you expected.

Comment: I'm a little unclear what exactly _base_dict.update() does for you here tbh.

Answer (score 0):

It's always helpful to draw out your data structure leads to less confusion. The issue can be resolved by adding a key to the dictionary if not already present else we can just update our dictionary with the new data.

```py
_base_dict = {}
'''
'Turing': 'State1': Votes , 'State2': Votes, ...
'Lovelace': 'State': Votes , ...
'Dijkstra': ...
'''
class elections:
  
  def add_state(state: str, data: dict[str, int]) -> None:
      global _base_dict  
      
      for name, votes in data.items():
        if(_base_dict.get(name) == None):
          _base_dict[name] = {state: votes}
        _base_dict[name].update({state: votes}) 
        
  def winner(college: dict[str, int]) -> str:

      global _base_dict

      rv = None
      bigger_percentage = 0

      for state, total_votes in college.items():
          majority = total_votes // 2

          for name, votes in _base_dict.items():
            # print(f"name:{name}  votes:{votes}\n")
            # print(f"state:{state}  total_votes:{total_votes}")
            try:
              if votes[state] > majority:
                  percentage = votes[state] / float(total_votes)
                  if percentage > bigger_percentage:
                      bigger_percentage = percentage
                      rv = name
                  elif percentage == bigger_percentage:
                      rv = None
            except:
              pass
          
      
      if rv is None: 
        return "No Winner"
      return rv

  def clear() -> None:    

      global _base_dict

      _base_dict.clear()
      _base_dict.update(_base_dict)
    
college = {'Virginia': 13,
'Ohio': 18,
'Minnesota': 10,
'Alabama': 9,
'Maine': 4
}

print(elections.winner({}))


elections.add_state('Virginia', {
'Turing': 15,
'Lovelace': 20,
'Dijkstra': 10
})

elections.add_state('Ohio', {
'Turing': 1,
'Dijkstra': 15
})

elections.add_state('Alabama', {
'Turing': 10,
'Lovelace': 20,
'Dijkstra': 8
})

print(elections.winner(college))

elections.add_state('Minnesota', {
'Lovelace': 10,
'Dijkstra': 30,
})

elections.add_state('Florida', {
'Turing': 10,
'Lovelace': 30,
'Dijkstra': 15
})

print(elections.winner(college))

elections.clear()
elections.add_state('Maine', {
'Turing': 2,
'Dijkstra': 1,
'Lovelace': 5
})
print(elections.winner(college))
```

```
No Winner 
Lovelace 
Dijkstra  
Lovelace
```